# PHP explode array with 2 types of separators

Tags: php, arrays, explode

I have this options array:

```
string(111) "colors:black;white;transparent;pink;"
```

how can I explode it so I get as a label first separator : and the rest in array as options? I have this so far:

```
$options= explode(";",$rows[0]);
$htm= '<ul class="product_opts">'.$lang['available_options'].'';
foreach ($options as $value) { 
        $row=mysql_fetch_row($result);
            $htm.='<li style="text-align:left;font-weight:normal;">'.$value.'</li>';
            }
        $htm.= '</ul>';
        }
    echo $htm;
```

but it returns the label as option too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = "colors:black;white;transparent;pink;";

list($label, $optionsStr) = explode(":", $str);

$optionsStr = rtrim($optionsStr, ";");
$options = explode(";", $optionsStr);

echo "<pre>";
print_r($label);

print_r($options);
```

Comment: Nice solution guys, Thank you all of you ! @enterx I accept yours as fastest answer, thanks !

Answer (score 2):

```
$attributes="colors:black;white;transparent;pink;";

list($attribute, $values) = array_map(
    function($value) {
        return array_filter(explode(';', $value));
    },
    explode(':', $attributes)
);
var_dump($attribute);
var_dump($values);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Explode string by `:`. First token will be your label, second token your options.
2. Explode second token by `;`, and you have your options in an array.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
$str = "colors:black;white;transparent;pink;";
$arr = explode(";",$str);
$key = explode(":",$arr[0]);
$arr[0] = $key[1];
unset($arr[sizeof($arr)-1]);
```

See demo [here](https://eval.in/108099)

Answer (score 0):

use `split` to do like so

```
$options= split("[;|:]",$rows[0]);
```

Comment: __Note:__ This function (split) has been DEPRECATED as of PHP 5.3.0.